# jquery isotope hide element then insert it

Tags: jquery, insert, jquery-isotope

I use jquery isotope to display my portfolio.
I try to insert hidden elements to isotope container.

To do this I remove on load elements, then I try to insert it on click.

However, removed elements don't want to appear again after click.

How can I do this?

Here a fiddle example of what I do : http://fiddle.jshell.net/s5TBU/

Sorry for my English, I'm French

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you removed your elements from the DOM using the remove method, they cannot be selected anymore. You can keep them in some variable before removing them if you want to insert them again afterwards OR maybe the hide method would be enough for what you want to do, and your elements would still be selectable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to use hide function, however the elements are "still" in the isotope container (there aren't displayed but still inside). I tried like this desandro example : http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/KWvME/. However I didn't success because one element can have several filter class. I don't know what to do....

Comment: Try the [first method](http://fiddle.jshell.net/s5TBU/1/). I only commented 1 line to make it work. You should do some research to understand the range of vars in JS, that would definitely help you.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand your previous answer. When I recreate the var=$removeItem , the element .hide searched wasn't hardcoded after removed it, So it was impossible to find it and to append it.

Comment: It's just that you erased you $removeItem var when you tried to search for the elements again, while $removeItem still contained them. And for the good of stackoverflow, please accept the answer.